# Get a broadcast from service on click(activity)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, service, broadcastreceiver

I have a service that is running in background, that is responsable for catpuring location changes and those stuffs.

On my activity i need to recover the last location **when i click on a button**, like taking a picture, when i click to send i want to get the data on the service.

I tried to send the data trough a broadcast, but is not working as expected, i try to access a method inside the service when my button is pressed.

**This is my service** (just important code)

```
   public void connected() {
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getApplicationContext(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                        30);
            }
        }

            location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if(location != null){
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                altitude = location.getAltitude();
            }


            final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            };

            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 500, locationListener);

        }

    public void getBroadcastData(Intent i) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        altitude = location.getAltitude();
        Log.d("latitude",String.valueOf(latitude));
        Intent intent = new Intent(i);
        intent.setAction("com.myapp.LOCATION_CHANGED");
        intent.putExtra("latitude",latitude);
        intent.putExtra("longitude",longitude);
        intent.putExtra("altitude",altitude);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

as you guys can see i have the getBroadcast method, on my activity when i press to send the image i want to capture that data.

**Activity**

```
private void sendImage(byte[] b) {
        ImageStore.getInstance().setCapturedPhotoData(b);
        GoogleLocation.getBroadcastData("com.myapp.LOCATION_CHANGED");
```

**Broadcast receiver activity(register dynamic)**

**onCreate(inside activity)**

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver;

IntentFilter filter;

MyReceiver reciver;



filter = new IntentFilter("com.myapp.LOCATION_CHANGED");
reciver = new MyReceiver();



public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("receiver","received");
    }
}
```

**then i register and unregister it**

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("com.myapp.LOCATION_CHANGED");
        reciver = new MyReceiver();
        registerReceiver(reciver, intentFilter);
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(reciver != null){
            unregisterReceiver(reciver);
            reciver= null;
        }

    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onPause();
        if(reciver != null){
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
            reciver = null;
        }

    }
```

i tired this way, but it says that it must be static on the other side, i can't access non static methods from a static context, if i change to static on the service it doesn't work as expected.

Any tip?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you share your code for the BroadcastReceiver, you have to use one if you haven't.
replace your getBroadcastData method with this--

```
private static void sendMessageToActivity(Location l, String msg) {
Intent intent = new Intent("LocationUpdates");
// You can also include some extra data.
intent.putExtra("Status", msg);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putParcelable("Location", l);
intent.putExtra("Location", b);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

}

in the activity --

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(
        mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("LocationUpdates"));
```

also in the activity--

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Get extra data included in the Intent
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("Status");
    Bundle b = intent.getBundleExtra("Location");
    lastKnownLoc = (Location) b.getParcelable("Location");
    //do whatever with lastknownLoc
}
```

};

Comment: if nothing works then use the service object itself (as singleton).

Comment: what is the msg?

Comment: any string, like a status of your location

Comment: i am still trying, in this situation how you unregiste your receiver on stop?

Comment: public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
  }

Comment: makes sense hehe wait a moment i will share with you if i did it

Comment: it doesn't enter myReceiver :/

Comment: i mean onreceiver

Comment: it will never work because my method is never triggered